# Didn't work my query builder code( whereRaw("DAY(time) = ?", $day )

Tags: php

My code is `whereRaw("DAY(time) = ?", $day)->get();`

But my code didn't work now...

I don't understand because `whereRaw("DAY(time) = ?", 5)->get()` is do work.

Why didn't work `$day` code?

I get use time `Carbon::now()` and get day `$time->day`;

`DAY(time) = ?", $day)->get()` < don't work

`DAY(time) = ?", 8)->get()` < work

I don't understand.

```
$result = DB::table('show')->whereYear('time',$year)->whereMonth('time',$month)->where(function ($mQuery){$mQuery->whereRaw("DAY(time) = $day")->whereRaw("HOUR(time) >= ?", $hour)->orWhereRaw("DAY(time) > $day");})->get();
```

Sorry, my English bad.

Comment: `$mQuery->whereRaw("DAY(time) = $day"` doesn't work or `DAY(time) = ?", $day)->get()`? Is one of those a typo in the questions?

Comment: doesn't work.
sorry my code is this.
$result = DB::table('show')->whereYear('time',$year)->whereMonth('time',$month)->where(function ($mQuery){$mQuery->whereRaw("DAY(time) = $day")->whereRaw("HOUR(time) >= ?", $hour)->orWhereRaw("DAY(time) > $day");})->get();

---- and return response()->json($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved this question.

I didn't use this

> use ($day, $hour)

<< So, My code didn't get $day, $hour ...

My code $day, $hour is null.

Change my code ->

```
$result = DB::table('board_show')->whereYear('time',$year)->whereMonth('time',$month)->where(function ($mQuery) use ($day, $hour) {$mQuery->whereRaw("DAY(time) = ?", [$day])->whereRaw("HOUR(time) >= ?", [$hour])->orWhereRaw("DAY(time) > ?", [$day]);})->get();
```